# Iphone app as a link

Tags: iphone

An Iphone app with a redirect to website is allowed? We have developed the web based application for hr people and I just want to have our name listed in the iphone app.

Comment: Do you mean the app has other features, then maybe on the Settings page there is a web link?

Answer (score 4):

Per the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), no.

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Comment: I don't think is wise to post parts of these guidelines as they are kind of private :). I don't think you want to violate apple's nondisclosure agreement

Comment: These guidelines are widely available on the public Internet.

Comment: officially they are a part of the developer program and they are not to be shared according to the nondisclosure agreement ... leaving that aside, copies of them are indeed all over the internet

Comment: Thanks for comments. I guess we can't do it then.